# Redirect user to a static page when server's usage is over a limit

Tags: php, mysql

We would like to implement a method that checks mysql load or total sessions on server and 
if this number is bigger than a value then the next visitor of the website is redirected to a static webpage with a message Too many users try later.

Comment: Do you have any server health monitoring tools installed into your database server?

Comment: Sounds to me like you might just need better caching...?

Comment: Yes maybe it needs better caching but it is a live website and we cannot make major changes in code for now. It is accepted if we show users a message try later. Maybe can we do it we mysql's show status and check the value of a variable? Can you make a suggestion on mysql's status variables?

Comment: Yeah, your proposed solution is very user-unfriendly.

Answer (score 0):

One way I implemented it in my website is to handle the error message MySQL outputs when it denies a connection.

Sample PHP code:

```
function updateDefaultMessage($userid, $default_message, $dttimestamp, $db) {
    $queryClients = "UPDATE users SET user_default_message = '$default_message', user_dtmodified = '$dttimestamp' WHERE user_id = $userid";
    $resultClients = mysql_query($queryClients, $db);
    if (!$resultClients) {
        log_error("[MySQL] code:" . mysql_errno($db) . " | msg:" . mysql_error($db) . " | query:" . $queryClients , E_USER_WARNING);
        $result = false;
    } else {
        $result = true;
    }
}
```

In the JS:

```
function UpdateExistingMsg(JSONstring)
{
    var MessageParam = "msgjsonupd=" + JSON.encode(JSONstring);
    var myRequest = new Request({url:urlUpdateCodes, onSuccess: function(result) {if (!result) window.open(foo);} , onFailure: function(result) {bar}}).post(MessageParam);
}
```

I hope the above code makes sense. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives to user-lock-out that I have used in the past to decrease load:

### APC Cache

PHP APC cache (speeds up access to your scripts via in memory caching of the scripts): http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&ix=c2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+apc+cache

I don't think that'll solve "too many mysql connections" for you, but it should really really help your website's speed in general, and that'll help mysql threads open and close more quickly, freeing resources.  It's a pretty easy install on a debian system, and hopefully anything with package management (perhaps harder if you're using a if you're using a shared server).

---

Cache the results of common mysql queries, even if only within the same script execution.  If you know that you're calling for certain data in multiple places (e.g. client_info() is one that I do a lot), cache it via a static caching variable and the info parameter (e.g.

```
static $client_info;
static $client_id;
if($incoming_client_id == $client_id){
return $client_info;
} else {
 // do stuff to get new client info 
}
```

---

You also talk about having too many sessions.  It's hard to tell whether you're referring to $_SESSION sessions, or just browsing users, but too many $_SESSION sessions may be an indication that you need to move away from use of $_SESSION as a storage device, and too many browsing users, again, implies that you may want to selectively send caching headers for high use pages.  For example, almost all of my php scripts return the default caching, which is `no cache`, except my homepage, which displays headers to allow browsers to cache for a short 1 hour period, to reduce overall load.

Overall, I would definitely look into your caching procedures in general in addition to setting a hard limit on usage that should ideally never be hit.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be done in PHP. You should do it naturally by means of existing hard limits.

For example, if you configure Apache to a known maximal number of clients (`MaxClients`), once it reaches the limit it would reply with error code `503`, which, in turn, you can catch on your [nginx](http://nginx.org/) frontend and show a static webpage:

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;
error_page 503 /503.html;
location = /503.html {
    root /var/www;
}
```

This isn't hard to do as it may sound.

PHP isn't the right tool for the job here because once you really hit the hard limit, you will be doomed.

Answer (score -1):

The seemingly simplest answer would be to count the number of session files in `ini_get("session.save_path")`, but that is a security problem to have access to that directory from the web app.

The second method is to have a database that atomically counts the number of open sessions. For small numbers of sessions where performance really isn't an issue, but you want to be especially accurate to the # of open sessions, this will be a good choice.

The third option that I recommend would be to set up a chron job that counts the number of files in the ini_get('session.save_path') directory, then prints that number to a file in some public area on the filesystem (only if it has changed), visible to the web app. This job can be configured to run as frequently as you'd like -- say once per second if you want better resolution. Your bootstrap loader will open this file for reading, check the number, and give the static page if it is above X.

Of course, this third method won't create a hard limit. But if you're just looking for a general threshold, this seems like a good option.

Comment: The problem with this method is that it counts the number of all sessions. But we maybe for 5 minutes we have 1000000 users that visit our site but the next 10 minutes with have zero. If we count the number of sessions in the 10 minute we would count 100000 open sessions, but they are there just because the session timeout is 20 minutes. So I would prefer somehow to check mysql's usage or server's usage and based on that value to redirect the next user.